# Android/Java "Convert" String to Button

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

String object = "button";
int num;
num = r.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1;
String total = object + num;
```

I want do set the text for one of the buttons chosen randomly. Something like this:

```
button<num>.setText(some_text);
      ^ here instead of <num> should be 1 or 2
        and has to be chosen randomly
```

Comment: What, in words, is it you want to happen? Do you want to set the text on one of your buttons?

Comment: Y, the num will have 1 or 2, so the total string will be "button1" or "button2".

Comment: I just dont know why i have "-1" if i have a question to ask. Please help me. I realy need know how to do this.

Comment: `total.setTest(some_text);` You want to change the text of a string?

Comment: No, i want change the text of the button. The total.setTest(some_text); is just a idia.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that `total` is a String, not a button.

Comment: I'm assuming total is a way of "selecting a random button". Unfortunately, that is not the way to do so. You should arrange your buttons in an array (or similar) and select a random index from that array. Then alter the text of the button at that array index. However, it may seem as though some basic programming tutorials might be in order.

Comment: Ok, thanks to the tip. I'll try but can you help me?

Comment: Why the coments have been delected? I want help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Ondkloss said, you can add your buttons to an array, then randomly select one from that array.

```
Button[] buttonArray = new Button[2];
buttonArray[0] = button1;
buttonArray[1] = button2;

Random r = new Random();

buttonArray[r.nextInt(2)].setText(someRandomText);
```

Keep in mind that if you change the number of buttons you will need to change the numbers that I have used (`new Button[`**2**`]` & `r.nextInt(`**2**`)`). My solution works specifically for an array of length 2 containing only 2 buttons. But other than changing the numbers in the array creation and the random number generation to match the number of buttons you have, this solution should work just fine.

Comment: I just dont vote up becouse dont have 15 reputation ^^

Comment: That's cool. If you gain some rep and remember, come on back :)

Comment: You can ease the code by using `Button[] buttons = { button1, button2 };`

Comment: By the way, for future posts, it is better to edit your answer than deleting the answer and posting a new one.

Comment: Why exactly is that better? I deleted the first one as to remove the erroneous comments. I will do whatever is better in the future, but I really did think I had done the better option.

Comment: I don't say it is better code, I said it eases the code (readability) :). For your second though, moderators can review the post and remove such comments, so you're not really enhancing the performance of the site by posting several answers on the same topic, that's why EDITs exist.

Comment: I'm still curious why having a deleted post is a "bad" thing. I can delete it, or I can wait until moderators come around and spend time removing comments that are no longer needed which I see as wasting their time when I can just simply delete them all in one click myself. In terms of the code you suggested, I agree it is better. I wasn't referencing that at all in my previous reply.

Answer (score 0):

> No, i want change the text of the button.

Then just do something like this

```
button1.setText("Just some strings here");
```

Comment: The problem is that OP wants the button that is getting its text changed to be random.

Comment: I want change the text of a random button. But problem solve thanks anyway.

Comment: Y, sorry my englisj is low.